# How can i do this function again when i slide to left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phonegap

i am doing a app in phonegap and i go get the information with JSON.

What i want to do is when i slide left to do this function again with ajax.

I have this code.

Thank you all for help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/fatos_random?filter[orderby]=rand&per_page=1",
        success: function(results){

           var texto = results.content.rendered;
           var imagem = results.better_featured_image.source_url;

           $('.text-center').html(texto);
           $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imagem + ')');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a navigation plugin for your navigation props, and attach an event to this plugin. When you do a slide left wrap a function to the code and call it when the event is triggered.
You could probably look into this plugin:

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions/tree/be41c76